# Dependency on multiple classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am new to Spring and need to expose web service to save Customer data.My customer object is huge json with multiple repeating elements .
I have seperate classes for each of these like Name,Address,Identification,Characteristics etc
Now when I define the POJO for Customer I need to declare all the dependencies ,have preferred Constructor based DI for this.

I have read many articles stating that Class should have single responsibility and multiple dependencies on other classes is a sign of bad design
Now my question is ,
Since my object is huge ,how can i reduce these dependencies as all of these are a part of my root Object-Customer.
Thanks.

```
Sample data :
{
   "customer": {
      "partyId": "9000073442",
      "partyRole": [
         {
            "partyRoleId": "CRM000"
         },
         {
            "partyRoleId": "CRM004"
         }
      ],
      "name": [],
      "associationName": [],
      "mobileNumber": "+919387439865",
      "emailId": "ipbl@ril.com",
      "status": "CUSA",
      "IndividualIdentification": [
         {
            "id": "POA",
            "type": "FS9200",
            "number": "23456789",
            "issueDate": "2018-01-04",
            "placeOfIssue": "MUMB",
            "issuingAuthority": "RTO"
         },
         {
            "id": "POI",
            "type": "FS9200",
            "number": "23456789",
            "issueDate": "2018-01-04",
            "placeOfIssue": "MUMB",
            "issuingAuthority": "RTO"
         }
      ],
      "PanIdentification": {
         "number": []
      },
      "characteristics": [
         {
            "attributeName": "DOC_REF_NUM",
            "attributeValue": "EM000000155Q"
         },
         {
            "attributeName": "ROUTING_ZONE",
            "attributeValue": "CO007"
         }
      ],
      "segment": {
         "attributeName": "CUSTOMER_CATEGORY",
         "attributeValue": "0007"
      },
      "associatedPartyId": "9000073441",
      "organization": {
         "name": "IPBillingLocation",
         "type": "0007",
         "designation": [],
         "department": []
      },
      "customerUpdationDateTime": "2018-02-08T12:24:31.776Z",
      "addresses": {
         "validFrom": "2018-01-28T18:30:00Z",
         "addressId": "0001980438",
         "subUnitNr": "23456",
         "buildingName": "sadfgh",
         "streetName": "asdfgh",
         "landmark": "sdfgh",
         "locality": "Ghansoli S.O",
         "postcode": "400701",
         "city": "Mumbai",
         "district": "Thane",
         "state": "MH",
         "country": "IN",
         "jioCenterId": "I001",
         "addressType": "PER_ADD"
      },
      "customerCreationDateTime": "2018-01-29T19:10:05",
      "circleId": "MU",
      "aadharIdentification": {
         "number": []
      }
   },
   "response": {
      "interactionStatus": "0"
   },
   "jioroute": "CO007"
}
```

My Customer POJO :

```
public class Customer{

  @Autowired
  private IndividualIdentification Indid;

  @Autowired
  private Characteristics chars;

  @Autowired
  private Addresses  addresses;


  // upto n 
}
```

Does this align with the best practice ? If not what is the alternative to reduce dependency

Comment: A Customer POJO, intended to be marshalled/unmarshalled to/from JSON, doesn't have any other responsibility than holding the data of a customer. Containing an Address is not really having a dependency. The address is simply part of the customer. Now, is it a good idea to display as much data when displaying a customer, and even worse, to save as much data at once when saving a customer, most probably not. Do you really intend to have a single page allowing to edit all that information at once?

Comment: I have added sample data and Pojo Customer.Could u advice whether this aligns with the best practice

Comment: No, it doesn't. Address, etc. are not dependencies of Customer, and all these classes shouldn't be Spring beans, and should thus not use Autowired, as explained by the two answers you already got.

Comment: @JBNizet : Then can u pls tell me how do i manage Address etc . ?

Comment: `Address address = new Address(); Customer customer = new Customer(address);` It's just plain old Java objects. Nothing to manage.

Comment: customer is taking address object..this is what dependency is all abt isnt it ? and address is passed externally bt in my case Customer Json will arrive at once .Pls correct me if i m wrng

Comment: No, not really. This is just data composition. It would be a dependency if customer offered services whose implementation relies on other services offered by Address. Jackson will create and populate addresses and customers for you. Just read the documentationn of Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

Model classes should not be dependencies managed by Spring.
You  generally create them in methods or "receive" them from the WS invocation after the request unserialization.
The model instances created from a WS invocation are methods bound and specific to a WS request.
So injecting them in a bean doesn't make sense.
Use rather method parameters to transmit them through the layers.

Model classes should be POJOs (or JPA entities if you use the same class both for the JSON and the persistence layer) but never Spring beans.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bit of misunderstanding regarding what classes are supposed to do.

You only need to register and inject dependencies into Spring context for services, controllers, Data Access Objects (DAO, communicate with databases), Repositories, Configuration.

The class "Customer" should be instantiated and handled by you.